How to send credential's(Passes) from Web app to Apple Wallet
I want to generate the passes from web app and pass the credential's to apple wallet for accessing the doors.
How to generate & pass the credential's(Passes) from the web app after the Apple Sign In from web app?
Want to send the credentials to Apple wallet so that Apple wallet will handle the credentials using NFC.

We want to send the credential's which are generated from Web app to Apple wallet
